# How to map between android.os.Build values to retail device names?

Tags: android

My android application records logs of connected devices, with infos such as:

- android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
- android.os.Build.DEVICE
- android.os.Build.MODEL
- more...

On top of that, I use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to log crash reports.

With these two sets of datas, I should be able to track what is going wrong, for each manufactorer and model of Android phone.

My problem is the following: I can't link the references returned by `android.os.Build.*` with the devices names.
For example, I just got a comment from the Android market saying "It sucks. Doesn't work on Acer Liquid". But I can't find the matching records in my data sets, because I have no idea how Acer Liquid is represented in `android.os.Build.*`.

I'd like to find a list of match between the devices names and the values possibly returned by `android.os.Build.*`. Do you know any please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this list, it isn't perfect but it may be helpful - http://pages.videotron.com/therau20/nr16/AndroidSuppDevices.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this website: http://www.glbenchmark.com/.  It has build information of many Android devices.